# Ranking items by score and relative frequencies

Tags: algorithm, ranking

I want to rank item types by comparing the ratio of frequency in basket 1 over frequency in another basket 2.

For example, if item type A has about 5 counts in basket 1 and 0 counts in basket 2, this should rank much higher than type B with say 10 items in basket 1 and 10 items in basket 2. I use the odds ratio `abs(log(freq in basket1/freq in basket2))`, however this doesn't capture the fact that I should prioritize `abs(log(10/100))` as `abs(log(1/10))`.

I'm thinking whether to add multiply this result by their the total count e.g `(10+100)abs(log(10/100))` but then again this amount seems to overwhelm the log value.

What would be a good suggestion to weigh the log values?

Comment: Difference between the frequencies will give me some value. Sorting these values should solve your issue right? The sorted list will give you the ranking.

Comment: @pala, not really. Say if i have [1,2], [100,101], but they don't really mean the same thing.

Comment: In your question typeA had a higher rank then typeB. How is it? and also what is the difference between [1,2] and [100,101]?

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach to these types of tasks is to model the item as a biased coin that produces baskets, B1 with probability `p` and B2 with `1 - p`. Intuitively this means that an item type has an underlying true ratio of baskets which produces a particular split of items between baskets. So a "90% A" might produce [9,1] but also [10,0] or even [0,10] although this result with a pretty low probability.

Then you can look at a sample like [5,0] and [10,1] and calculate a confidence interval for the parameter `p`, then rank the item types by the lower bound of the interval. This way [10,2] will sort above [5,1]. Even though proportions in both samples are the same, [10,2] will have a narrower confidence interval and thus its lower bound will be higher.

The idea and some more detailed formulas is described at: http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html